# setting aggregated features

Tags: java, oop

My question is, you can set the room paremeters on instantiation of the room class, but how can you set the properties of the aggregated features of the room class e.g the walls properties and windows properties? because I would rather not use setters? is there another way?

As I can instantiate rooms, and then I have to add instances of the walls and windows invidually? As I could instantiate 3 rooms, each room has different window and wall sizes?.

```
  ROOM CLASS < AGGREGATED WALL ARRAY LIST < AGREGGATED WINDOWS ARRAY LIST
```

Thanks

Comment: Some context would be useful. E.g. what are the fields of the Room class?

Comment: and what do you mean by 'the aggregated features' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Yes, contructor. LIke</strike>

```
public class Room {

    private List<Window> windows = new ArrayList<Window>();
    private List<Wall> walls = new ArrayList<Wall>();
    private List<Door> doors = new ArrayList<Door>();

    public Room(int windows, int walls, int doors){
        for(int i=0; i < windows; i++)
            windows.add(new Window());
         //similarly for walls and Doors :)
    }

     //getters
}
```

**Update** from comment: The OP wanted to avoid setters, and it turned out that Windows may be of different type. It seems that this is some kind of testing of ability to make composition, the `has-a` thing.

I guess you need this. *Figure out!*

> **NOTE:** I have written this in this editor, for conceptual understanding purpose, code may not compile

```
//you see rooms have walls, and many. So constructor takes List of 
//windows and doors in each wall. So, a List of walls that has List 
// (mixed bag) of windows and doors in each wall -- some may have no 
//window/door, then 2nd list will be empty.
public class Room {

    List<Wall> _walls = new ArrayList<Wall>();

    public Room(List<List<Openable>> walls){
        for(List<Openable> windowsOrDoors : walls){
            this._walls.add(new Wall(windowsOrDoors));
        }
    }
}

//wall can have many doors and/or windows. We pass out mixed 
// bag list here, constructor will figure out how to keep 
//them in separate lists
public class Wall {

    List<Door> doors = new ArrayList<Door>();
    List<Window> windows = new ArrayList<Window>();

    public Wall(List<Openable> openables){
        for(Openable windowsOrDoor : openables){
            if(windowsOrDoor instanceOf Window)
                this.windows.add(windowsOrDoors);
            else
                this.doors.add(windowsOrDoors);
        }
    }
}

//Window class, simple class -- it is of type Openable
public class Window implements Openable{
    public Window(int w, int h){
        //do something
    }
}

//Door class, simple class -- it is of type Openable
public class Door implements Openable{
    public Door(int w, int h){
        //do something
    }
}

//Openable -- a common interface to Window and Door, you can use 
//abstract class here and have getHeight, getWidth and other common 
//methods. This just for the purpose that if you wanted to add another 
//Window/Door class like `ArchedDoor` which has a `radius` as well, 
//you will just write a `ArchedDoor implements Openable` and pass into 
//the Room/Wall constructor. Nothing will break. 
public interface Openable{}
```

Comment: But what about if each window has a differrent sizes? will that have to bet set with setters? because a forloop will just create them all the same?

Comment: see you have the most flexible room ever. (:

Comment: haha! now you have totally lost me haha but it looks good!, could you do me one last favour and comment some of it please? so I can figure it out that way? Many thanks for your time!

Comment: mainly whats the openable and windowsordoors bit about? is there meant to be something inside the interface?

Comment: `windowsOrDoors` is just a variable name, so that you understand that it is list of mixed stuffs. Nothing to do with compiler, it's just for reader's clarity! `windowsOrDoor` is the element from this list which I have to determine what it is, and then put into appropriate list. Btw, added comments. Good luck.

Comment: Hey Nishant sorry to trouble you again, how do you create the Nested list to send to the constructor?? like in a factory method or something?.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand you,

but you can add parameters to the constructor of a room and then initiate the walls of the room with these parameters as arguments to their constructors (you can add parameters to their constructors as well)

your constructor can look something like this:

```
public Room(WinSize[] windowsSizes, Color[] wallsColors){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < WinSize.length ; i++)
    {
        windows.add(new Window(windowsSizes[i]));
    }
}
```

(Lets say you have some classes like WinSize etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Some context is missing from this question, but in general, I can say that yes, you won't create public setter for aggregated, calculated fields.

Usually you have private methods that update the calculated fields and these methods are called from the constructors and/or from the setters of the public fields (that is, the calculated fields are updated every time the public fields are modified).